# Django serializer not returning all fields in response

Tags: python, django

I have following serializer in Django. The serializer is however not returning all the fields in the response. 'amount' and 'amount_ordered' are not returned, all other fields are.. key point: these are the only 2 fields I have in my model. So I thought I only need to add them in the fields list?

```
class AdminOrderItemSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    purchase_order = serializers.CharField(source="get_purchase_order")
    reference = serializers.CharField(source="get_reference")

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = [
            "purchase_order",
            "reference",
            "amount",
            "ordered_amount",
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass
```

Model:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    ordered_amount = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="order_items"
    )

    def get_purchase_order(self):
        return self.order.purchase_order

    def get_reference(self):
        return self.order.reference
```

Comment: _'amount' and 'amount_ordered' are not returned, all other fields are_ The model does not contain a field named `amount_ordered`.

Comment: I noticed. I edited it, it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 2):

Use **`serializers.ModelSerializer`** instead of `serializers.Serializer` as

```
class AdminOrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # your code
```